Wix toolset: Custom images are not loading on the MSI installer
I am in desperate need of help. I have been stuck on this problem for days now and have been looking all over the internet, you are me last hope.
I've been trying to create a Windows Installer using WIX and all seems well until I try to customize the standard UI's (minimal to be specific).
I am trying to apply custom images on the installer wizard I kept my bmp files in the installer folder along with remaining files I want to pack. But the custom messages and images not applying to installer. Blow is my code snippets,
    <Package InstallerVersion="500" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <Property Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="E:\WixToolset\CRMWixProject\CRMSetup\Images\banner.bmp" />
        <Property Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="E:\WixToolset\CRMWixProject\CRMSetup\Images\dialog.bmp" />
        <Property Id="CustomWelcomeMessage" Value="Welcome to the CRM Setup Wizard. This wizard will guide you through the installation of MIMICS CRM. Click Next to continue." />

............
       <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <UI Id="CustomWixUI">
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" Bold="yes" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

            <Dialog Id="CustomWelcomeDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup">
                <Control Id="Banner" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="58" Text="[WixUIBannerBmp]" />
                <Control Id="WelcomeText" Type="Text" X="135" Y="20" Width="220" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="{\WixUI_Font_Title}[WelcomeDlgTitle]" />
                <Control Id="Description" Type="ScrollableText" X="20" Y="70" Width="330" Height="120" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no" Text="[CustomWelcomeMessage]" />
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="60" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="[Button_Next]" />
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="60" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="[Button_Cancel]" />
            </Dialog>

            <Dialog Id="CustomExitDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup">
                <Control Id="Banner" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="58" Text="[WixUIDialogBmp]" />
                <Control Id="Finish" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="60" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="[Button_Finish]" />
            </Dialog>

            <DialogRef Id="InstallDirDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="VerifyReadyDlg" />
            <Publish Dialog="CustomWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="CustomExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg">1</Publish>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>

I am expecting to apply my messages and images in installer wizard
